# Transfer Data to Time Range

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database something like this:

```
DateAndTime           Column1  Column2  Column3 ... Column85
============================================================
2016-01-01 00:00:10      1       0        0            0
2016-01-01 00:00:20      1       0        0            1
2016-01-01 00:00:30      1       1        0            1
2016-01-01 00:00:40      1       1        0            0
2016-01-01 00:00:50      0       1        0            0
2016-01-01 00:01:00      1       0        0            1
2016-01-01 00:01:10      1       0        0            1
2016-01-01 00:01:20      1       0        0            0
2016-01-01 00:01:30      0       0        0            0
...
2016-01-11 00:01:30      0       0        0            0
```

I am using LinQ to retrieve the data.

```
var Data = (from row in db._Data where row.Column86 == X select row).ToList();
```

Is it possible to generate result output something like this or similar:

```
Column1
From 2016-01-01 00:00:10 To 2016-01-01 00:00:50
From 2016-01-01 00:01:00 To 2016-01-01 00:01:30
Column2
From 2016-01-01 00:00:30 To 2016-01-01 00:01:00
...
Column85
From 2016-01-01 00:00:20 To 2016-01-01 00:00:40
From 2016-01-01 00:01:00 To 2016-01-01 00:01:20
```

The following is the code I try:

```
        bool alarmhistory = false; // Check if there is a true for whole table
        bool from = false; // If previous 1 is activate
        bool gotAlarm = false; // Check if there is a true for whole column

        string RawHtml = "";
        string FinalHtml = "";

        RawHtml = "<tr><td style='text - align:center; '><b>";
        RawHtml += "Column1";
        RawHtml += "</b></td></tr>";
        RawHtml += "<tr><td>";

        for (int x = 0; x < Data.Count ; x++)
        {
            if (x == 0 && Data.Count != 1) //First Row 
            {
                if (Data[x].Column1 == 1)
                {
                    gotAlarm = true;
                    alarmhistory = true;
                    from = true; // Start the time
                    RawHtml += "From " + Data[x].DateAndTime.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
                }
            }
            else if (x == 0 && Data.Count == 1) //First Row but only have 1 record
            {
                if (Data[x].Column1 == 1)
                {
                    gotAlarm = true;
                    alarmhistory = true;
                    from = false; // Only 1 record, meaningless
                    RawHtml += "From " + Data[x].DateAndTime.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
                    RawHtml += " To " + Data[x].DateAndTime.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
                }
            }
            else if (x == (Data.Count - 1)) //Last Row 
            {
                if (Data[x].Column1 == 1)
                {
                    gotAlarm = true;
                    alarmhistory = true;
                    if (from == true)
                    {
                        RawHtml += " To " + Data[x].DateAndTime.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
                    }
                    if (from == false)
                    {
                        RawHtml += "From " + Data[x].DateAndTime.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
                        RawHtml += " To " + Data[x].DateAndTime.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
                    }
                }
                if (Data[x].Column1 == 0)
                {
                    if (from == true)
                    {
                        RawHtml += " To " + Data[x].DateAndTime.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
                    }
                }
            }
            else //Others condition 
            {
                if (Data[x].Column1 == 1)
                {
                    gotAlarm = true;
                    alarmhistory = true;
                    if (from == false) // If previous is 0
                    {
                        RawHtml += "From " + Data[x].DateAndTime.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
                        from = true; // Start the time
                    }
                }
                if (Data[x].Column1 == 0)
                {
                    if (from == true) // If previous is 1
                    {
                        RawHtml += " To " + Data[x].DateAndTime.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
                        RawHtml += "<br />";
                        from = false; //End the time
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        RawHtml += "</td></tr>";

        if (gotAlarm == true)
        {
            FinalHtml += RawHtml;
        }

        RawHtml = "";
        gotAlarm = false;
        from = false;
```

After that I will repeat and change the Column1 to Column2. But system will stack overflow after Column16 I think.

Comment: What format is the output supposed to be in, a string? A custom data structure? Does the answer have to be entirely in LINQ? Have you tried anything? If so post what you've tried.

Comment: Yes, a string. Actually is a Html format. Not restrict to LINQ. Yap I try do 85 loops request the columns but when I reach around 16 columns system stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication29
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("DateAndTime", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Column4", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01 00:00:10"), 1, 0, 0, 0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01 00:00:20"), 1, 0, 0, 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01 00:00:30"), 1, 1, 0, 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01 00:00:40"), 1, 1, 0, 0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01 00:00:50"), 0, 1, 0, 0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01 00:01:00"), 1, 0, 0, 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01 00:01:10"), 1, 0, 0, 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01 00:01:20"), 1, 0, 0, 0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01 00:01:30"), 0, 0, 0, 0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01 00:01:30"), 0, 0, 0, 0 });

            for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; colIndex++)
            {
                List<List<DateTime>> results = GetRanges("Column" + colIndex.ToString(), dt);
                if (results != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Column" + colIndex.ToString());
                    foreach (List<DateTime> result in results)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("From {0} To {1}", result[0].ToString(), result[1].ToString());
                    }
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static List<List<DateTime>> GetRanges(string colName, DataTable dt)
        {
            List<List<DateTime>> results = new List<List<DateTime>>();
            List<DateTime> newResult = null;
            Boolean foundStart = false;

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                int state = (int)row[colName];
                if (!foundStart)
                {
                    if (state == 1)
                    {
                        //add start time
                        newResult = new List<DateTime>();
                        results.Add(newResult);
                        //add date as both start and end incase there is only one item
                        newResult.Add((DateTime)row["DateAndTime"]);
                        newResult.Add((DateTime)row["DateAndTime"]);
                        foundStart = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (state == 0)
                    {
                        foundStart = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newResult[1] = (DateTime)row["DateAndTime"];
                    }


                }
            }
            if (results.Count == 0)
                return null;
            else
                return results;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The result seems is exactly what I need. The rest is how to convert the data to DataTable.

Comment: All database interfaces have an Adapter (ie SQLDataAdapter) which will take a select query and put results into a DataTable.